# How Do I Refactor Common React Components?

Tags: reactjs, refactoring, material-ui

I am styling a *required* `TextField` [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/5yyo503794)

```
const styles = theme => ({
  labelAsterisk: {
    color: "red"
  },
  cssLabel: {
    color: "orange"
  },
  cssRequired: {
    "&:before": {
      borderBottom: "2px solid orange"
    }
  },
});


    <TextField
      id="requiredField"
      label="Required Field"
      value="Custom Text"
      required
      InputLabelProps={{
        classes: {
          root: classes.cssLabel
        },
        FormLabelClasses: {
          asterisk: classes.labelAsterisk
        }
      }}
      InputProps={{
        classes: {
          underline: classes.cssRequired
        }
      }}
      margin="normal"
    />
```

I have lots of these required fields in my forms and would like to standardise it instead of copying and pasting large chunks of code.

What is the best way refactor this so that I only need to specify `id`, `label` and `value` each time I use it?

Do I extend `TextField`?

Create a new component that extends `React.Component`?

Use a function or a constant?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you would define your custom TextField component:

```
const RequiredTextField = ({id, label, value}) => (
  <TextField
    id={id}
    label={label}
    value={value}
    required
    InputLabelProps={{
      classes: {
        root: classes.cssLabel
      },
      FormLabelClasses: {
        asterisk: classes.labelAsterisk
      }
    }}
    InputProps={{
      classes: {
        underline: classes.cssRequired
      }
    }}
    margin="normal"
  />
)
```

And here's how you would use it:

```
<RequiredTextField id="some-id" label="some-label" value="some-value">
```